# How to return custom response for `Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException`?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

In my controller, I used the method `firstOrFail()` for a database query with *Eloquent*. When in debug mode, I get a Laravel error message with the content `Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException`.

However, I'd like to return a `redirect()` or mabye `back()` instead of showing this error screen. How can I do that?

Comment: You should use first() Instead of firstOrFail() and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `firstOrFail()` use `first()` and use condition to redirect back, for example:

```
$item = Item::where('slug', $slug)->first();

if (! $item) {
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [php try catch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), to override the behaviour of error catching,

```php
          try {
            // your functional code
            } catch (Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException $exception ) {
            //your redirect command , the code here will be executed if there is an exception with type ItemNotFoundException 
            }
```

if you want to catch all errors, you need to use the General Exception class which is the parent of all Exceptions

```php
          try {
            // your functional code
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            //your redirect command , the code here will be executed if there is any exception 
            }
```

if you want to get the exception message to log it or any customization , you can use the method : `getMessage()` , in our case will be `$exception->getMessage()`

Comment: You should add some explanation, so other can learn from it.

Comment: sure I will edit that